# Correct way storing object list

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a country list below which is an object.

[image]

I also have a Market list:

[image]

I want it so that within the France Object there is another set of Object which lists all the sector. I tried saving the list as Country.list[country][sector]= self; but to no avail. How would I overcome this? The code:

[image]

Effectively I want to create a multidimensional JS object, which goes into a specific country, then goes into the sector of the country.

Comment: Could you add the code you use (see [mcve]), the expected outcome, and what is happening with your current code?

Comment: can you share the code for the list over here  ?

Comment: Hi. Instead of using screenshots to show your code, you should copy/paste it and format it as code. It makes it easier to reproduce your problem and helps people answering your question. As suggested above, a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example helps even more

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to give string (not variable) as the key of sectors

```
Country.list[country]['sector'] = self; // notice, it is string
```

Comment: Nope getting "Cannot set property 'sector' of undefined"

Comment: `Country.list[country].sector = self;`

Comment: Same issue I'm getting

Comment: is `country` variable a country object or string?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking..

If you need all sectors related to france from `Market` and add them to `Country` list .. then you can try this.

```
 var sectors = [];

    $.each(Market.list, function(key, value){
     if(value.country == "France"){
       sectors.push(value.sector);
      }
    });
```

This will add all sectors related to `France` in `sectors` array. Now we assign this array to main `Country.list`

```
Country.list[France].allSectors = sectors ;
```

Comment: Sorry I should be a bit clearer. Effectively I want to create a multidimensional JS object, which goes into a specific country, then goes into the sector of the country.

Answer (score 0):

All your attributes are currently set in the same flat object. As you meant you have to nest them.

In `Country` you have to create a new object and assign it to the corresponding attribute in `Country.list` if it doesn't exist yet. This object will get itself the same treatment for the sector.

The following code (in `Country`) will certainly be clearer than my poor explanation :-)

```
if(!Country.list[country])Country.list[country]={};
Country.list[country][sector]=self;
```

Note that the `country` attribute should be set to the parent object in the list :

```
if(!Country.list[country]){
   Country.list[country]={'country' : country};
}
Country.list[country][sector]=self;
```